# SQLite transpose using recursive CTE

Tags: sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression, transpose

Given this input data:

```
SEQ_ID SP_ID MASK STRING G_ID DEPTH PRESSURE
97 52361796 1 1 1 5.37 1941.0
97 52361796 1 1 2 5.77 1986.0
97 52361796 1 1 3 6.65 1922.0
....
97 52361800 1 1 1 5.76 1926.0
97 52361800 1 1 2 5.39 1922.0
97 52361800 1 1 3 6.85 2092.0
```

How do I transpose it like this:

```
SP_ID MASK P_01 ... P_027 D_01 D_027
52321798 2 0 ... 2084.0 ... 0 ... 2084.0 ...
52361796 1 1941.0 ... 0 ... 5.37 ... 0 ...
52361800 1 1926.0 ... 0 ... 5.76 ... 0 ...
```

Code so far that created above output:

```
    CREATE TEMP VIEW IF NOT EXISTS vInteractive AS 
    SELECT 
        SP_ID 
        , MASK 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN G_ID=1 THEN PRESSURE END) AS P_01 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN G_ID=27 THEN PRESSURE END) AS P_27 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN G_ID=1 THEN DEPTH END) AS D_01 
        , SUM(CASE WHEN G_ID=27 THEN DEPTH END) AS D_27 
    FROM vGun 
    GROUP BY SP_ID 
    ORDER BY SP_ID 
    ;
```

I was wondering if instead of this brute force approach of coding n number of lines, I can do something smarter with recursive CTE.

It is a given that I know the max of G_ID to put a cap on recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) has a fixed number of columns, so this is not possible.